# KnockoutJS calling observable properties

Tags: knockout.js, observable

In KnockoutJS, why we need to call the observable member of a view model as a function, for instance in the below snippet while retrieving the values of **currentProfit** is called as **currentProfit()**.  Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks

```
var viewModel = {
        currentProfit: ko.observable(150000)
    };

 viewModel.profitStatus = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return this.currentProfit() < 0 ? "profitWarning" : "profitPositive";
    }, viewModel);
```

Comment: It is explained here:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: Not all browsers support JavaScript getters and setters (* cough * IE * cough *), so for compatibility, ko.observable objects are actually functions.

To read the observable’s current value, just call the observable with no parameters. In this example, myViewModel.personName() will return 'Bob', and myViewModel.personAge() will return 123.

the above excerpt answers my doubt, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already found out [*why*](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables) knockout uses the pattern it does, but it might be fun to explore if it can be changed. Especially since the main reason was to support older browsers.

Here's a quick exploration of how you could use your `observable`'s default methods inside a `get` and `set`. If you'd want to, I'm sure you'll be able to extend this to also use `ko.computed`s (`typeof model[prop] === "function"`) and `ko.observableArray`s (`Array.isArray(model[prop])`).

If anybody has some more knowledge on `Object.defineProperty` and how to make `subscribe` and other methods accessible, please feel free to add to this answer/comment. Personally, I'd be very interested in a new version of knockout supporting this syntax :)

```js
const viewModel = {
  currentProfit: 1500
};

const makeObsGetSet = (model, prop) => {
  const innerObs = ko.observable(model[prop]);
  
  Object.defineProperty(model, prop, {
    get: innerObs,
    set: innerObs
  });
  
  return model;
};

// Mutate the vm to have obs. property
makeObsGetSet(viewModel, "currentProfit");

console.log("get without ():", viewModel.currentProfit);

// Subscribe to show it worked:
// (if anybody knows of an easier way to make subscribe 
// accessible from the outside, let me know!)
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(viewModel, "currentProfit").get.subscribe(
    v => console.log("New currentProfit value:", v)
);

// Write using `= 2000` instead of `(2000)`
viewModel.currentProfit = 2000;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```